# Spring boot Auto Restart Self After JAR Update

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot JAR on a linux server located at some directory `/dev/ExampleApplication.jar`.

Is it possible for the Spring Boot application to monitor that specific JAR for an update (maybe a change in the checksum), and if there is an update, shut itself down, and start the updated JAR?

I want something like this in pseudo code:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void checkForUpdates() {
  long fileChecksum = getJarChecksum();
  if (checksum != fileChecksum) {
    command("java -jar /dev/ExampleApplication.jar");
    context.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: Look into Kubernetes or AWS Fargate. This can cause many problems and headaches. And this is a very ugly approach to DevOps.

Comment: instead of self reloading/restarting, just have a cron job (shell script), which will do the same for you, and be sure that it will take down time of your application

Comment: @AlanSereb Yeah this probably going to be a mess. I can't use any of those container technologies.

Comment: I'm just wondering if it is possible.

Comment: write a shell script as @RamiReddyP pointed out

Answer (score 3):

You could use [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) to re-launch the jar file any time it is deleted or altered.

You'll need to install inotify-tools on your Linux distro if it is not already.

```
while inotifywait -e close_write /dev/ExampleApplication.jar; do java -jar /dev/ExampleApplication.jar; done
```

The -e parameter takes an event type.  You can also watch a directory to see if anything is deleted or created in that directory.  See here for more on the inotifywait event types: https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait